# How to determine duplicate elements in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I try to compare elements of array with each other during for loop. In my case, I have some duplicate values that I couldn't delete for some reasons but I have to determine them.

Here is what I have and it's not working for me

```
int x;
int table[] = {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10};

for (x = 0; x <= table.length; x++) {
    if (x == 0 || x + 1 < table.length) { //determine that element is not last
        if (table[x] == table[x + 1]) { //determine if next element is the same
            System.out.println(table[x] + "if x = x + 1");
        }

        //determine that element is equal to previous but not equal to next
        if (table[x] != table[x + 1] && table[x] == table[x - 1]) {
            System.out.println(table[x] + " if x != x + 1 but x = x - 1");
        } else {
            System.out.println(table[x]);
        }
    }

    if (x + 1 == table.length) { //determine that element is last
        System.out.println(table[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your table guaranteed to be sorted?  Or, put another way: if there are duplicates, will they be all together in the table?

Comment: Please explain the problem more. I didn't understand the requirements.

Comment: Just FYI : The above code works only if you have a sorted array.

Comment: yes,i will put sorted data in it @ajb

Comment: I have data that will be load to array,and it has dublicate elements inside.I need to determine this elements without removing it.I can use hashSet for it@Multithreader

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: @ajb for now just to add some comment near this element.Something like this 
`1 
 2 dublicated 
 `

Comment: you don't want to store duplicate values in 'Array' ?

Comment: @HArdik i'll store it,i don't want to remove it

Comment: okay then may be my post is not useful for you.

Comment: please select a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of errors in your code,

```
int x;
int table[] ={1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,10};

for (x = 0; x < table.length; x++){ // <-- NOT <=
  if (x + 1 < table.length){ //<-- what if the table only has one element?
    if (table[x] == table[x + 1]) { // <-- Add a {, Java is hard to read without
             //                            braces.
      System.out.println(table[x] + "if x = x + 1");
    } else if (x > 0 && table[x] == table[x - 1]) { // <-- check that x is
                                     // greater then 0 before subtracting 1
        System.out.println(table[x] + " if x != x + 1 but x = x - 1");
    } else {
        System.out.println(table[x]);
    }
    if (x + 1 == table.length){ //determine that element is last
      System.out.println(table[x]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ummm, are you sure the `{` on the 6th line should be added?  You just fixed things so that the next `if` will never be true since its first part contradicts the `if` condition on the 6th line.  I think it was right not to have `{` there but his indentation was just sloppy.

Comment: @ajb I reached that conclusion as well. Edited.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i check position of element just after for loop
`if (x == 0 || x + 1 < table.length){ //determine that element is not last `

Comment: @IlgarMamedov I see that. And what do you do when x == table.length? So why do it?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch when i reach last element i just print it and break it ...i forgot to put ` break ` statement))

Answer (score 0):

there are numerous ways to do this with the JDK.  This task would be much easier to do if you use the Collections classes instead.  For example, you could follow this procedure:

1. convert your array into a List object (ArrayList for example)
2. Then construct a new Set instance (HashSet for example) and provide the list from the first step as a constructor argument.  The set will only contain unique integers, you can continue working with that alone, or follow the next step if you want to find the duplicates.
3. Unfortunately you can't use the 'removeAll' method to get duplicates.  You will probably have to write a for loop over the set in step 2, and invoke the remove method on the list from step 1.  Since the 'remove' method will only remove the first occurence, you should wind up with a list of just the duplicates.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

also, if you're willing to add a dependency on guava or apache commons collections, they each have a good Multimap implementation that might help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HasmMap for that then.
If you have an array such as [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 8, 4]
it will give you a map: {[1 -> (0,6)], [2 -> (1,2)], [3 -> (3)], [4 -> (4, 8)], [5 -> (5)], [8 -> (7)]}

```
// mapping from number to indexes in the array where duplicates of number exists
HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> duplicates = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
for(int i=0; i < table.length; i++) {
    int current = table[i];
    List<Integer> dubList = duplicates.get(current);
    if(dubList == null) {
        dubList = new ArrayList();
        duplicates.put(i, dubList);
    }
    dubList.add(current);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code

```
HashSet hs = new HashSet();
int table[] ={1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,10};
for (int x = 0; x < table.length; x++)
{
    hs.add(table[x]);
}
System.out.println(hs);
List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>(hs);
System.out.println(array);
```

Now You can get idea...